# Get last node in Firebase database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get item in the last node added in firebase database from my Android. You can see on the image below i'm not sure how to get the specific node, because unique key is created by Firebase. How to reference to auto-created node and child inside? Thanks a lot

The last node

[image]

Comment: here is good example of firebase database https://androidheight.blogspot.in/2017/04/firebase-reatime-database.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("mp").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Handle possible errors.
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Change that line into this `String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();`

Comment: @koceeng Sorry! I forgot that, you were totally right. I changed my answer!

Comment: It works!! i had to update my code from orderByChild() to orderByKey() to obtain rightly

Comment: Great to hear that @Billyjoker!

Answer (score 5):

This might work:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("mp");
Query query = db.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("User key", child.getKey());
            Log.d("User val", child.child("message").getValue().toString());
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // TODO: Handle errors.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write and retrieve data through objects.
MyObject is POJO.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        MyObject myObject = data.getValue(MyObject.class);
        Log.i(TAG, data.getKey() + " = " + myObject.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log('last messages', messages[messages.length-1]);