# How to get last three added childs from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to store my data. I know how to add children, edit, delete and get all children from a specific node. Is there a solution to get last three added children from a specific node? Here is my database:

[image]

This is how I normally get all the children:

```
actionDatabaseReference = basketballDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(UID).child("teams").child(teamkey).child("games").child(gamekey).child("actions");
actionDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot actionDataSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            final Actions action = actionDataSnapshot.getValue(Actions.class);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601147/get-last-node-in-firebase-database-android), but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [limittilast() method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Query.html#limitToLast-int-).

which 
**Create a query with limit and anchor it to the end of the window**

Comment: Than you for your help. Query did the job for me.