# How to find latest node in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to create database which include some products. Every product should has name , price , id , location. I want to make id primary key and make it increment.

I already tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601524/5532932. But I couldn't make it work.

This my DatabaseManager class I use it for write to database. Here is the part for write to production table.

```
    private DatabaseReference receiptDatabase;

    public DatabaseManager(){
        receiptDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    //Declarations for production table
    public void writeNewProduct(String id, String name, double price, Date date){
        Product product = new Product(id,name,price,date);

        receiptDatabase.child("product").child(id).setValue(product);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to get latest id of saved product. And increment it so I can insert next node with this incremented id.

My database should able to save more than one from same product name. But their id must be different. If you have any other suggestion to make this happen I am open for any suggestion.

An example table should be like this.

/ 1 / coke / xx place / 5$ /

/ 2 / milk / yy place / 6$ /

/ 3 / coke / zz place / 4$ /

/ 4 / bread/ xx place / 1$ /

/ 5 / coke / xx place / 5$ /

Comment: This is only how you set a value in the database. Show us how you query the database.

Comment: I couldn't make it yet. How can I make query the database. I am very new to firebase.

Comment: Why the answer that you saw first didn't work?

Comment: when I do that solution and deploy it to my phone app crashes. When I make comment this solution it works. I don't know why. I try to use "message" variable to get latest element but I failed.